# How do i display the first principal component of an image after doing PCA (using SVD)?

Tags: pca, unsupervised-learning, svd

Suppose i have an 10 images with 100x100 pixels. I have already converted the data into a 10x10000 dataset, subtracted the mean and performed SVD to get the eigenvectors and eigenvalues. Now i want to display the first and second principal components as images but im not sure how ? Would it just be the eigenvectors or would i have to multiply it by the dataset to get the principal components ?

Comment: I think you should be using a square matrix.

Comment: See eigen-faces related bibliography. They are concerned *exactly* this kind of tasks.

Comment: @kugar: Just convert each eigenvector but to $100 \times 100$ matrix. That's the image it represents.